# Unable to modify Excel from ASP.NET CORE

Tags: c#, excel, asp.net-core

I have ASP.Net core project and class library associated. In class library I have my code to update Excel file. It works fine when used in unit test or called from native console app. But it neither throws exception nor modify/update excel file when called from web app.

```
public bool SaveOrder(Order order)
{
    excelApp = new Excel.Application();
    excelBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(_dbPath);
    orderMenuSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelBook.Worksheets.get_Item(2);
    try
    {
        foreach (var menu in order.OrderItems)
        {
            var rowNum = menu.MenuNumber + 2;
            orderMenuSheet.Cells[rowNum, 3] = menu.Menu;
            orderMenuSheet.Cells[rowNum, 7] = menu.Rating;
            orderMenuSheet.Cells[rowNum, 8] = menu.Review;
        }
        excelBook.Save();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
    finally
    {
        DisposeExcelObject(); //dispose excel objects
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: @ESG,as mentioned in question, it doesn't give exception

Comment: Sounds like you are using `com`. Have you considered to use OpenXml SDK or will you install excel on a web server ? BTW: http://joelleach.net/2018/06/06/com-interop-with-net-core-2-0/

Comment: 1. If you're using the [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel/](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel/), I could reproduce the same issue as yours . **When targeting `.netcoreapp2.2`, most of operations fail silently except that getting the sheet name succeeds**. But it works fine if I target `.net472`.  2. Are you targeting `.NET Framework` ? Note this library is not compatible with `.NET Core` yet.

Comment: It works fine with .net  framework. I do agree that something is going wrong with .net Core. Even when I save file as new file, new file is created but doesn't contain the changes I made. It just creates copy of existing file.

Comment: @tschmit007 yes I'm using com components. I'll definitely think about OpenXml SDK. excel is installed on server. But doesn't seem to be working not event locally.

Comment: @tschmit007 using openXML worked for me. Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

i change some code and its works for me.i Hope it will help

```
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo oldCI = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");

        // Creating Excel Application
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = oldCI;

        var fileName = Path.Combine(_he.WebRootPath + "\\ClientFile", "test.xlsx");
        var excelBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(fileName);
      var  orderMenuSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)excelBook.Sheets["QUESTIONNAIRE PACK"];
            foreach (var menu in order.OrderItems)
            {
                var rowNum = menu.MenuNumber + 2;
                orderMenuSheet.Cells[rowNum, 3] = menu.Menu;
                orderMenuSheet.Cells[rowNum, 7] = menu.Rating;
                orderMenuSheet.Cells[rowNum, 8] = menu.Review;
            }
            excelBook.Save();
```

Comment: @SriaPathre Sorry, misunderstood about this ticket.  I am try getting data instead of edit. I  can now edit excel .i just update my code and it works for me

Comment: As discussed above, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel doesn't work with ASP.NET core. It silently fails without exception. So changed my code to OpenXML and works fine now. Thanks for your efforts @jalil.